# Java classes (Outputting numbers)

Tags: java

My team is making a project that displays big digits in hash codes.
We imported a local library: ScoreboardNumbers

Example, if the user enters 4, the output is:

```
       #
     # #
   #   #
 #     #
 # # # # #
       #
       #
```

So the program is here below and we can't seem to find out what the problem is with one of the lines. I posted the whole code just in case we messed up somewhere else.

Thanks for helping guys!

//Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digit: ");
    int dig = scanIn.nextInt();
    Score digit = new Score(dig);
    digit.getScoreArray();
    String strDigit = ScoreboardNumbers.get(Digit.getScoreArray()); //Red squiggly under the '.getScoreArray()'
    Scanner scanStr = new Scanner(strDigit);
    int col = 0;
    while (scanStr.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.print(scanStr.nextInt() == 1 ? " #" : "  ");
        col++;
        if (col % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

//Instantiable class Digit

```
public class Digit {

    private int digit;
    private final int ROWS = 7;
    private final int COLS = 5;

    public Digit(int digit) {
        this.digit = digit;
    }

    public boolean[][] getDigitArray() {
        boolean[][] arr = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];
        String strDigit = ScoreboardNumbers.get(digit);
        Scanner scanStr = new Scanner(strDigit);
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;
        while (scanStr.hasNextInt()) {
            arr[ROWS][COLS] = (scanStr.nextInt() == 1);
            col++;
            if (col % 5 == 0) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

//Class: Score

```
public class Score {

    private int score;

    public Score(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public boolean[][][] getScoreArray() {
        int digit1 = score / 10;
        int digit2 = score % 10;

        Digit d1 = new Digit(digit1);
        Digit d2 = new Digit(digit2);

        boolean[][][] scoreArray = {
            d1.getDigitArray(),
            d2.getDigitArray()
        };
        return scoreArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: @shree.pat18 Sorry. I added the problem but I think it got erase. Anyway, I got added a comment where the problem is.

Comment: I edited the code, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to know the difference between instance method and static method.

**A. Static Method**

1. Static method are those which are **declared with** the `static` keyword.
2. Static method can be called by using the instance, instance variable or the class name.

**Example :**

```
public class MyCalculator{
    public static int powerOf(int number, int power){
        .... some code here...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyCalculator x = new MyCalculator();
        int answer1, answer2, answer3;
        answer1 = x.powerOf(3, 6); //Correct
        answer2 = MyCalculator.powerOf(4, 2); //Correct
        answer3 = new MyCalculator().powerOf(4, 2); //Correct
    }
}
```

**B. Instance Method**

1. Instance method is **declared without** the `static` keyword.
2. Can be called by an instance or instance variable.

**Example :**

```
public class MyCalculator{
    public int powerOf(int number, int power){
        .... some code here...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyCalculator x = new MyCalculator();
        int answer1, answer2, answer3;
        answer1 = x.powerOf(3, 6); //Correct
        answer2 = MyCalculator.powerOf(4, 2); //FALSE
        answer3 = new MyCalculator().powerOf(4, 2); //Correct
    }
}
```

The line `String strDigit = ScoreboardNumbers.get(Digit.getScoreArray());` on your code calls the static method getScoreArray() from the class Digit which does not exist, thus, generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to access a method that's not static as if it were a static method. You need to call the getScoreArray() function on an actual Score instance, not on the class itself. Perhaps you want the 'digit' object? In which case it would be digit.getScoreArray(), rather than Score.getScoreArray().

Comment: I did that earlier, but then it had a red squiggly under 'getScoreArray()'

Answer (score 0):

> 1 *getScoreArray()* belongs to Score class not digit class
>
> 2 *getScoreArray()* is not static method.